# When boot option with "iommu=off intel_iommu=off ", it will cause IBM x3650 M4 IMM remote console cannot work properly

Tags: linux, grub

CPU: Intel E5-2660 v2
OS: CentOS 7.9
When I added "iommu=off intel_iommu=off" in grub boot option, it can boot successfully. But IMM (BMC) remote console (IBM video viewer) cannot use keyboard (type any key take no effect).
A little curiousness what reason for it?